# Reserving space for list

Tags: python, list

I have to make list2 which use name from list1 but number of name in list1 can vary.

```python
foo = ['spam', 'eggs']
bar = [['spam', ['a', 'b']], ['eggs', ['c', 'd']]]
```

So, I reserve `bar` by

```python
bar = [[None] * 2] * len(foo)
```

and copy names from list1 by looping

```python
 bar[i][0] = foo[i]
```

but the result is the name in every sublist are the same like this

```python
bar = [['eggs', ['a', 'b']], ['eggs', ['c', 'd']]]
```

I try to reserve by

```python
bar = [[None, None], [None, None]]
```

and no issue at all. So I think the problem come from how I reserve the list.

How can I fix this. If you don't understand my English, please ask. Thanks.

Comment: why do you need to reserve ?

Comment: @ismailsunni can you index an empty list?

Comment: The first way makes a duplicate reference for the lists. If you were to debug your code, you'd see name1 get assigned correctly in the first list, then overwritten like you see

Comment: Thank you cricket_007 and yes, I don't know the other way to do that without indexing that list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your second list like this:

```
list2 = [[None]*2 for x in range(len(list1))]
```

or alternativly, if for some reason you don't like to use comprehensions, you could do

```
list2 = []
for x in range(len(list1)):
    list2.append([None,None])
```

The problem is that when you do something like

```
[listItem] * numCopies
```

you get a list that contains *numCopies* copies of **the same** *listItem*, so your sublists are all the same - when you change one you change them all.

The way that I have suggested will create unique lists that contain the same content (two copies of `None`).  Thus changing one of these sublists will not change any others.

Comment: Thank you, Matthew. Now I understand my result of sublist.

Answer (score 3):

Python `list` type is for contiguous sequences, not arrays. (Python does have an array type, but `list` is not that.)

The example data structure you show (a sequence of pairs, with a single name and a collection of values) would be IMO better served by a mapping. Python's built-in mapping type is `dict`.

```python
foo = ['spam', 'eggs']
bar = {
        'spam': ['a', 'b'],
        'eggs': ['c', 'd'],
        }
```

So there is no need to reserve space in a Python `list` nor a Python `dict`. Just assign and delete items as you need, and the collection will manage its own space.

When you want to set items in the mapping `bar` keyed by the values you already have in the list `foo`, you just use a value from the list as a key in the dict:

```python
for name in foo:
    value = determine_what_is_the_value_for(name)
    bar[name] = value
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know well about mapping ,so i will use this next time.